# If $ f \in C_0^\infty$, then is $f$ uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

If $ f \in C_0^\infty=\{ g: g\in C^\infty, \lim_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}g(x)=0\}$, then is $f$ uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$?
($ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $)

Comment: This is true. Hint: You can split $f$ up into a part where you can control it and a different part where it is very small

Comment: Doesn't this just follow from the fact that $f$ has compact support, is continuous on that compact set, and hence uniformly continuous on that set (and hence all of $\mathbb{R}$, since $f\equiv0$ outside of the set.)

Comment: Doesn't the $0$ in the subscript mean compact support?  Then it follows from being continuous on a compact set...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is an increasing, bounded and continuous function on $\[a,+\infty)$ uniformly continuous?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105310/is-an-increasing-bounded-and-continuous-function-on-a-infty-uniformly-con)

Comment: Note, the same could be said about $f\in C^{1}_{0}$.

Comment: The question itself is not an exact duplicate but all you need is that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x)$ exists. Which reduces this to the other question.

Comment: Thank you. I think it also holds for just $f \in C_0^1$.

Comment: @Patch I think the subscript $0$ denotes that $\lim_{|x|\to \infty} f(x) =0$, rather than compact support.

Comment: Oh. I'd never seen that notation before.

Comment: @Misaj It is prefered that when using non-standard notation, to give an definition or explainations in words what it means. Notice that sometimes different people using different notations, so not each notation is generally understood by all.

Comment: People from PDE use $C_0^\infty$ to denote compactly supported functions. People from harmonic analysis (like Rudin) use $C_c$ to denote continuous functions with compact support, while the subscript 0 is used for "vanishing at infinity".

Comment: I do not think that this is a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINTs**

1. A continuous function on a compact interval is uniformly continuous.
2. $\lim_{|x| \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ means that $\forall \epsilon...$
3. Split up the domain to use these two properties.